# Dynamic number manipulation inside input element, incremental addition

Tags: javascript

So the problem is that I have an Input window that shows up in a modal for a product.

For the problem's sake, the `input` appears focused, and therefore you can type in it right away. For the problem's sake, the default `value` property is `0.00`. Now, what I want to do is for the user to be able to dynamically input numbers that begin from the latest decimal place incrementally.

Example 1: We have the said input window with `0.00`. We want to type in the price `9.00`. We press `9` one time and `0` two times. The output is now `9.00`.

Example 2: We have the said input window again. We want to type in the price `39.42`. We press `3`, then `9`, then `4`, then `2`. The output is now `39.42`.

Now my problem is that my current code has some quirks and doesn't work as I expect it to, but I'm really out of ideas. What's killing me is also the fact that this problem is supposed to be trivial but I really cannot wrap my head around it.

The Problem: Very unreliable backspace/deletion behaviour. I tried detecting `event` on backspace button press and manipulate the value there, but it was just as unreliable.

Sidenote: I also think there should be a more graceful way of tackling this problem. Maybe `RegEx`?

Many thanks in advance.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/m2pjn74s/)

```js
let raw, semiRare, done;
const t = document.getElementById('t');

const getInput = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    raw = Number(t.value);
    semiRare = raw * 10;
  }, 1)
}
const setInput = () => {
  done = semiRare.toFixed(2).toString();
  t.value = done;
};
```

```html
<input id="t" type='text' onkeydown="getInput()" onkeyup="setInput()" placeholder="0.00" value="0.00">
```

Comment: Try this, paste text into the field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the key on `keydown` and prevent the default action.

```
<input id="t" type='text' placeholder="0.00" value="0.00">

<script>
    const t = document.getElementById('t');
    const digits = [];
    const numbers = '0123456789';

    const display = () => {
        t.value = (parseFloat(digits.join('') || '0') / 100).toFixed(2).toString();
    }

    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        const key = event.key;
        if (numbers.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            digits.push(key);
            display();
        } else if(key === 'Backspace') {
            digits.pop();
            display();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    t.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
</script>
```

Comment: `t.value = (parseFloat(digits.join('') || '0') / 100).toFixed(2).toString();`

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed. I honestly forgot about `preventDefault`, even though I work with React a lot lately. Well done!

Comment: keyCode is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss good catch, answer updated (can't test on NumPad but it should work too.

Comment: it's really a choice but `const isNumber = /^[0-9]$/i.test(event.key)` instead of the `numbers` array with the `.indexOf()` could be used and the `display();` can be passed the `display(event, digits);` and then that function can use the `event.currentTarget.value` and not rely on the global `t` and `digits`